# How does delete know the size of derived class from base pointer?

Tags: c++

I am curious how the delete operator know the size of the derived class when calling delete on base pointer, here is a minimal example:

```
class IVariant
{
public:
    virtual ~IVariant() = default;
    virtual void print_value() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Variant: public IVariant {};

template<>
class Variant<int>: public IVariant
{
private:
    int m_integer;

public:
    Variant(int integer): m_integer(integer) {}
    void print_value() override
    {
        printf("integer: %i\n", m_integer);
    }
};

template<>
class Variant<double>: public IVariant
{
private:
    double m_dbl;

public:
    Variant(double val): m_dbl(val) {}
    void print_value() override
    {
        printf("double: %g\n", m_dbl);
    }
};

template<>
class Variant<std::string>: public IVariant
{
private:
    std::string m_string;

public:
    Variant(const std::string& string): m_string(string) {}
    void print_value() override
    {
        printf("string: %s\n", m_string.c_str());
    }
};
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    IVariant* int_var = new Variant<int>(100);
    IVariant* dbl_var = new Variant<double>(100.0f);
    IVariant* str_var = new Variant<std::string>("the value is 100\n");

    int_var->print_value();
    dbl_var->print_value();
    str_var->print_value();

    delete int_var;
    delete dbl_var;
    delete str_var;
}
```

The delete operator correctly knew from the base pointer alone that `int_var = variant<int>` so freed 4 bytes, `dbl_var = variant<double>` so freed 8 bytes, `str_var = variant<std::string>` so it freed 28 bytes.

But how does it know? Does the new operator store size & pointer which the delete operator can then use to free the correct number of bytes? I know this is how delete[] works for arrays but I was unable to find any info when it came to derived classes

Comment: This is implementation defined. You will need to specify which implementation you want to know about for a meaningful answer.

Comment: In short, yes. The heap allocation has size and type information for each object that has been created. Calling delete will go to the lookup table and free the respective amount of bytes for the given object.

Comment: The default heap memory allocator of your standard library's `operator new` "knows" how much memory is owned by each pointer it handed out to you. Its the one responsible for the cleanup, of cause after the runtime has correctly called the appropriate destructor.

Comment: @callyalater "size and type information" - what type information does the heap allocator have?

Comment: @NirFriedman Some implementations will store template type sizes (which is what I meant by type information) when used in a typedef, using, or member variable context to determine what offsets to use and to provide type checking at runtime. But, the type information (if any) is implementation defined.

Comment: The basic way the allocation functions are implemented is a table with a pointer being mapped to a size (in bytes). Anything past that is implementation specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`delete` and `delete[]` operators know the size of the allocation, because operators `new` and `new[]` save some housekeeping information for them at the time of allocation. It uses the same idea as `malloc`/`free` pair, when `malloc` saves size information that is required for `free` to do its job.

Figuring out the allocation size is independent of the type for which the memory is allocated. Operators `delete` and `delete[]` do not even know the type of the pointer being deleted, because they operate on `void` pointers.